# Android Studio select deployment target

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, deployment-target

I was working on some app and had a device connected to the the computer,
also I had an emulator, both of them worked properly.
I d'ont know what happend but now I cant see any of them.
It says "nothing to show" when I open the window of "select deployment target"(after I click run).
What can I do?

This is the message :

[image]

Fixed

I went to the task manager and ended the process named adb.exe, and it worked.

Comment: You should better add an answer as to how it was fixed!

Comment: I went to the task manager and ended the process named adb.exe, and it worked.